# Have a lot (confidence VS self-confidence)

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

I was wondering which sentence is correct:

> **a)** He has a lot of **confidence**. 
>   **b)** He has a lot of **self-confidence**.

Actually, I've come across either case many times, but I sort of think "a" is the correct choice and "b" seems to be a direct translation from another languages. E.g.

[He doesn't care to play against Madrid than against another. **He has a lot of self-confidence**, he dares everything and has revolutionized and we thought we could.”](https://www.google.com/amp/s/sportsfinding.com/luaces-explains-what-he-thought-when-he-saw-zidanes-eleven/12538/amp/)

Please kindly explain to me whether "self" in "b" is superficial for the above context or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) is fine, but doesn't say what he has confidence in. It may be obvious from the context of the statement, or it may require some elaboration.

b) is also fine and adds what it is he has confidence in - himself. It probably does need expansion of what type of thing about himself he has that confidence, such as completing tasks of type A, or charming people of type B, and so on.

So both are fine and although b) is a bit more complete that a) both are, in fact, incomplete.